# TweenMax / GSAP stagger raw array values

Tags: javascript, gsap

Let's say I have the following arrays with just numbers:

`[0, 0, 0, 0]`

and

`[40, 50, 75, 80]`

How do I interpolate from the first to the second, using staggering/cycling (with GSAP)? (And with staggering I mean, first do the first item, then after some delay, do the next).

Note: I have already converted the single number values to objects so that GSAP can work with them (so `[{y: 0}, {y: 0}]` and so forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by the following question on the GSAP forum:

https://greensock.com/forums/topic/18692-interpolating-using-staggerto-from-one-array-w-values-to-the-next/

To make it possible to interpolate between a single value in a array (in this case, a number), I had to create a new timeline-like object for every value

```
var a = [0, 0, 0, 0];

staggerArray(a, [10,20,30,40], {duration:1, stagger:0.5, round:true});

//vars accepts: duration, stagger, round, as well as any typical vars for TimelineMax (like onComplete, onUpdate, repeat, yoyo, etc.)
function staggerArray(start, end, vars) {
  var tl = new TimelineMax(vars),
      proxy = {},
      duration = vars.duration || 0,
      stagger = vars.stagger || 0,
      proxyUpdate = function(original, proxy, i) {
        return function() {
          original[i] = proxy[i];
        };
      },
      v, i;
  for (i = 0; i < start.length; i++) {
    proxy[i] = start[i];
    v = {};
    v[i] = end[i];
    v.onUpdate = proxyUpdate(start, proxy, i);
    if (vars.round) {
      v.roundProps = i + "";
    }
    tl.to(proxy, duration, v, stagger * i);
  }
  return tl;
}﻿
```